# Deleted my OS, samsung galaxy s2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2

i was recently updating my OS for my galaxy S2 yesterday. during the update process. i accidentally switched off the phone and when i restarted my phone, the sscreen showed "SAMSUNG GALAXY SII GT-I9100G". and the screen was just displaying that eversince. i tried to remove the battery and fix it back in but didnt show any other results. my guess is i think my OS got deleted during that process. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: You can either reinstall the original firmware by downloading a matching factory firmware image from http://sammobile.com and flash it using Odin (Samsung's flash tool) or install an aftermarket firmware like [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/devices/samsung-galaxy-s2) ([install instructions](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_II)).

Comment: It would help if you could [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/46467/edit) your question to include what exactly you did. Just factory-resetting a device does not "delete" the OS from an Android device. Please include as well what happens when you boot your device: do you see the boot animation? Does anything happen at all?